# check the spinner data is the same as data inside database

Tags: java, android, firebase

i'm trying to redirect my login according to the spinner chosen by user but the spinner value should correspond with the value inside my database. I have an idea on how to do it but I still can't find a way to code it. I'm using android (java) with firebase (authentication & database) to log into the app.

below is a part of the code inside my MainActivity for the spinner

```
spinRole.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long id) {
                if (adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).equals("Role")){
                n = 0;
                }else if (adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).equals("Teacher")){
                    role.setText(adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    //do another if else
                    //read from database and if data snapshot same with the item at position
                    n = 1;
                    //else n = 0;
                }else if (adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).equals("Parent")){
                    role.setText(adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    //do another if else
                    //read from database and if data snapshot same with the item at position
                    n = 2;
                    //else n = 0;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
```

and this is how I logged in

```
else  if(!(emailID.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty()) && (n==1)) {
                    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailID, pwd).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Error, Please Login Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else{
                                    Intent intTeacher = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TeacherActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intTeacher);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else  if(!(emailID.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty()) && (n==2)) {
                    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailID, pwd).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Error, Please Login Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else{
                                    Intent intParent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ParentActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intParent);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error Occurred!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

This is my first time coding using android and firebase so I barely know anything, can someone help me?

Comment: Try to get your firebase data in a arraylist and set it as an adapter to the spinner , or if you don't want you can just use arraylist.contains("query") and be sure that the data belongs to database

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?